# How do I add five numbers from user input in Python?

Tags: python

As a practice exercise, I am trying to get five numbers from a user and return the sum of all five number using a while loop.  I managed to gather the five numbers, but the sum is not provided by my code (I get a number, but it is always double the last number).  I believe the issue is with my use of +=.

```
x = 0   
while x < 5:
    x += 1
    s = (int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")))
    s += s
print s
```

Comment: `s += s` is an odd thing.  What do you think that statement will do?  Please update your question with an explanation of that statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be better.

```
x = 0
s = 0   
while x < 5:
    x += 1
    s += (int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")))
print s
```

You were putting one of the results on to the sum of all results and lost the previous ones.

Answer (score 12):

Gruszczy already solved your main problem, but here is some advice relevant to your code.

First, it's easier to do a `for` loop rather than keep track of iterations in a `while`:

```
s = 0
for i in range(5):
  s += int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
```

Second, you can simplify it using the built-in `sum` function:

```
s = sum(int(raw_input('Enter a number: ')) for i in range(5))
```

Third, both of the above will fail if the user enters invalid input. You should add a `try` block to take care of this:

```
s = 0
for i in range(5):
  try:
      s += int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
  except ValueError:
      print 'Invalid input. Counting as a zero.'
```

Or if you want to force 5 valid numbers:

```
round = 0
s = 0
while round < 5:
  try:
      s += int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
  except ValueError:
      print 'Invalid input.'
  else:
      round += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding str or int by user_input & then printing the result -
[Adding 2 or more no's from users input](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html#numbers-and-strings-of-digits)

example from the abv link

```
'''Two numeric inputs, explicit sum'''

x = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
y = int(input("Enter another integer: "))
sum = x+y
sentence = 'The sum of {} and {} is {}.'.format(x, y, sum)
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
s = 0   
    while x < 5:
        x += 1
        s += (int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")))
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this also

```
print ("enter input number : ")

input1 = int(raw_input())

sum1 = 0

for y in range(0,input1+1):
       sum1 = sum1 + y
print ("the sum is " + str(sum1))
```