# Calculate sum of list of values entered by users

Tags: python, list, sum

I'm trying to help my son who's got some Python homework from school...and I haven't coded since school and this is my first evening on python so forgive the dumb question.

Using a "For" statement I need to prompt the user to enter 10 numbers. When the entries have ended, I need to display the sum. I know I need to do something linking newsum/oldsum/+ value entered but I'm stuck. All help gratefully received.

Here's where I've got to:

```
total=int
runningtotal=int
thisinput=int
n=0
for num in range (1,11):
runningtotal=thisinput+n
print("enter number",num)
n=int(input())
thisinput=n
print(runningtotal)
```

Comment: I imagine when you were coding back in school, you used static-typed languages (google that). Python's not static-typed. Also, for statements are different...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299890/how-do-i-add-five-numbers-from-user-input-in-python

Comment: I just removed the greetings and changed the formatting of the question slightly. Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

In python3.x, using your code as a working model, probably something like this:

```
runningtotal=0
for num in range(10):
    thisinput = input("enter number: ")  # If using python2.x change input to raw_input
    runningtotal+=int(thisinput)
print(runningtotal)
```

Another answer (was deleted) used [list.append()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to add numbers to list and [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) the list elements like so:

```
num_list = []
for num in range(10):
    thisinput = raw_input("enter number: ")
    num_list.append(int(thisinput))
print sum(num_list)
```

Comment: Thanks to all those who provided real code. As I said, I'm a complete novice. Where do I find on this site explanations for all the syntax you're using such as raw_input, numbers.append(number) etc? @Elliott Roberts, your comment was irrelevant. I asked for help, not to be point towards more of what I don't know.

Comment: @SJJHR, It looks like that other answer got deleted. And my apologies for not including more documentation in my answer. [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) is for python 2, which if you are running python 3 (which I think you are based on your use of `print()` is python 3 syntax) `raw_input` in python 2 got changed to just [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) in python 3. The `numbers.append()` syntax from the answer that was deleted is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures.

Comment: Please can the poster who used the numbers.append() syntax re-post it? Thank you

Comment: @SJJHR: No idea who posted that answer, but I've added the implementation they used to my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
inputs_sum = 0
for x in range(10):
    inputs_sum += int(input('Enter number:'))
print('The sum is {}'.format(inputs_sum))
```

Enjoy!