# Expense calculator gives result instead of asking user for input

Tags: python

I have homework that requires me to create an expense calculator where a user enters a starting amount. After your first input it’ll ask if you want to continue “y/n” if not it’ll subtract the first expense from your starting amount. And print the answer.

The problem is that it’s supposed to ask if I want to continue once again if I choose “y” and enter a second expense instead of “n”. The user is then supposed to select no (since there’s no third expense). Instead of letting me input no it just goes straight to the print function & gives me the answer.

```
startamount=int(input("Enter starting amount in account: "))
expense1=int(input("Enter expense 1: "))
answer=input("Do you want to enter another expense: (y/n) ")
if answer == "y":
    expense2=int(input("Enter expense 2: "))
    print("Do you want to enter another expense: (y/n) ")
elif answer == "n":
    sub1=startamount-expense1
    sub1=startamount-expense1
sub2=startamount-expense1-expense2
print("Amount in account before expenses subtraction: $",startamount)
print("Number of expenses entered: 2 ")
print("Amount in account AFTER expenses subtracted is: $",sub1)
```

Comment: startamount=int(input("Enter starting amount in account: "))

expense1=int(input("Enter expense 1: "))
answer=input("Do you want to enter another expense: (y/n) ")
if answer == "y":
    expense2=int(input("Enter expense 2: "))
    print("Do you want to enter another expense: (y/n) ")
elif answer == "n":
    sub1=startamount-expense1

sub1=startamount-expense1
sub2=startamount-expense1-expense2

print("Amount in account before expenses subtraction: $",startamount)
print("Number of expenses entered: 2 ")
print("Amount in account AFTER expenses subtracted is: $",sub1)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link under the post to put all additional information. Then, use the `{ }` button to format your code blocks to make it readable. Also, post the console output as text, not as images, because they are text.

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.comPlease/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

This is a homework problem so I won't give you a solution, rather I will point you to some helpful links that will allow you to figure this out on your own.

First lets plot out the expected logic.

1. Ask user to enter starting amount.
2. Ask user to enter an expense
3. Ask user if they want to enter another expense

   - If they choose "y", go to step 2.
   - If they choose "n", go to step 4.
4. Ask for the amount before expense subtraction.
5. Perform your logic to calculate the amounts you want to print.

Step 1 you have done correctly.

Step 2 and 3 you need to modify. You will notice from my example above, we have a case where we want to go back to `step 2`. To complete something like this, you would want to use a `while loop`. The condition for you breaking that loop should be if the user is done entering expenses and chooses "n".

- http://introtopython.org/while_input.html#Using-while-loops-to-keep-your-programs-running

You might be wondering how you can continually subtract expenses. You have already obtained your starting amount. Every time the user enters an expense, simply subtract it from your starting amount. Note that since you want to print the starting amount at the end, you might want to consider copying the starting amount into another variable, and subtracting from the new one.

- [How do I add five numbers from user input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299890/how-do-i-add-five-numbers-from-user-input-in-python)

I notice that you print the number of expenses entered. How can you track this? Perhaps you can keep a `counter` variable and increment it by 1 every time the user enters a new expense.

- See the first "EXAMPLE" from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm

Step 4 is simply printing the starting amount you took in. The number of times the loop ran. And the amount after subtracting all the expenses.

Comment: Thank you for not giving me the answer!! This was beyond helpful, the loop gave me trouble. But your help was great

Comment: @Careem you thank people by clicking the green checkmark at the upper left of their answer.