# Adding up user input in For Loop, Break after 0 input

Tags: python, for-loop, math

I need the user to key in as many integer inputs. I'm aware that I have to use a for loop. My issue is, how do I add up all the integers the user key in together? The for loop will only break when user key in 0.

Example: there's 100 stalls. The program will keep prompting which stalls the user visited until 0 is entered. User entered `1, 3, 6, 10, 20, 0`.
How do I program to add `1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 20 = 40`?

```py
for i in range(101):
   stalls = int(input("Enter stall number to visit: "))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add five numbers from user input in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299890/how-do-i-add-five-numbers-from-user-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 0
for i in range(101):
   stalls = int(input("Enter stall number to visit: "))
   sum+=stalls
   if stalls == 0:
       break
```