# How to sum 5 numbers in python with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, input, sum

I'm new to Python. I am attempting to write a 'for' loop that, during each iteration, accepts a number from the user.  After the loop is finished, it will output the sum of the numbers.  The loop should run 5 times.

I cannot figure out how to sum the numbers inputted. Here is the code I have so far, in which z should be the sum of the five inputted numbers:

```
z = 0
def func(y):
    global z
    z = y + z
for i in range(5):
    y = int(input("Enter a whole number here:"))
    func(y)
print("The sum of these numbers is {}.".format(z))
```

I figured out that when I originally defined the
func,I defined it as `func(z)` rather than `func(y)`.
Glad to know I was on the right path, though.

Comment: Initialize `z` to `0` before the loop. Add `y` to `z` each time through the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to initialize z = 0, but I still don't know how to add y to z each time. That is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Comment: @Barmar, I understand that. You are misunderstanding my question. I am trying to create a variable which adds the inputted variables 5 times, with a different input each time.

Comment: If you put that after the `input` line, it will do what you want.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2299959/2681662

Comment: We're trying to help you without completely holding your hand and doing it for you. We've given all the ingredients. You _already_ know that your loop runs 5 times. You _already_ know that the variable `y` contains a new value each time around the loop. You _now_ know how to add the variable `y` to the variable `z`. And the only thing left is for you to realize _where_ to put that line of code. Given everything I've just written, do you think that maybe you can figure it out, on your own, and feel the thrill of having learned something without it being handed to you on a platter?

Comment: I understand that. I tried to create this code for 1 and a half hours earlier using every concept except apparently the correct one. I apologize for sounding like I was asking for a handout.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the variable for the total before the loop. Inside the loop, add each number to the total.

```
z = 0
for i in range(5):
    y = int(input("Enter a whole number here:"))
    z += y

print("The sum of these numbers is {}.".format(z))
```

You could also use the built-in `sum()` function along with a generator instead of a `for` loop.

```
z = sum(int(input("Enter a whole number here:")) for _ in range(5))
print("The sum of these numbers is {}.".format(z))
```

Comment: This is weird. I literally tried this exact thing earlier, except that I created a function to do the adding, and it kept saying that the sum is 0. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Why didn't you put the function in the question? Then we could have helped you understand what you did wrong.

Comment: You can still edit the question now, and add the function.

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Standby. P.s. I figured out a simple mistake which impeded my progress. I figured out that in the function, I accidentally made it a function of z rather than a function of y.

Comment: Ugh, that design is so horrible I don't know what to say. Try to avoid using global variables.

Comment: Good to know. I’ll try to avoid globals in the future.